# Very slowly scroll on UITableView images

Tags: ios, image, uitableview, scroll

Very slowly scroll on `UITableView` images.Help me please.
Did not find the right solution
My code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *const ImageCellId = @"ImageCell";

    EXImageCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ImageCellId];
    RSSItem *item = [_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.cellTextLabel.text = item.title;
    cell.cellTimeTextLabel.text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:item.pubDate dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    cell.cellAuthor.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Author: %@", item.author];

    NSURL *tutorialsUrl = item.link;
    NSData *tutorialsHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:tutorialsUrl];
    TFHpple *tutorialsParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:tutorialsHtmlData];
    NSString *tutorialsXpathQueryString = @"//div[@class='photo']/img";
    NSArray *tutorialsNodes = [tutorialsParser searchWithXPathQuery:tutorialsXpathQueryString];
    //NSMutableArray *newTutorials = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    for (TFHppleElement *element in tutorialsNodes) {
        tutorial = [[Tutorial alloc] init];
        //[newTutorials addObject:tutorial];
        //tutorial.title = [[element firstChild] content];
        tutorial.url = [element objectForKey:@"src"];
    }
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL : [NSURL URLWithString:tutorial.url]];
    UIImage *imageMain = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    [cell.cellImageView setImage:imageMain];

    return cell;
}
```

PS:  `dispatch_async` tried to use, but to no avail

Comment: It's slow because you're using a synchronous network call `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL`

Comment: You are absolutely sure that your cells are being reused? Check you cell's identifier. I also assumed you registered your cell's class in the table view, since you don't check if cell is nil after calling dequeue. Another thing, why are you looping through tutorialsNodes? You only have on variable being changed inside :/
And the one I consider the most 'dangerous', are you doing networking on the NSData method?? Cause that will block, since its on the main thread :/

Comment: This question is duplicating one created less than 24hours before...
Your scrolling appear to be really slow because you are fetching your data inside your protocol `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, that's means every time a cell is displayed, it will request again.
Please check this post for more explanation : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584852/uitableview-scrolling-is-very-slow-it-use-the-network-for-every-scrolling/24585062#24585062
And make some research in SO website before posting